# To to posititon css elements above another elements without overlapping

Tags: css

I am trying to make a clock with css, but the borders between elements renders as a thin line, which I don’t want and am not sure why it’s there at all.

http://codepen.io/Domynyk/pen/qNJGxA

```
.second {
  z-index: 10;
  border: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid #4C5864;
  border-right: 30px solid #4C5864;
}

#second-hide {
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 30px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
  border-right: 30px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean not overlapping correctly? Can you give us an image of the desired behavior?

Comment: The white colored 'hider' elements are not covering entirely the element below them, its seems that all three of them have borders.

Answer (score 0):

To make the round corner look smooth, browsers draw them with a semi-transparent edge. Now if two corners that are drawn in the exact same way are overlapped, you will see the darker color shine trough on that border edge.

I'm afraid there is no possibility to avoid this. Maybe you can try to print your white "hide-borders" 1px greater, but that seems to be not suitable for your application.